# Function with diminishing return f(0)=1/2 and when x-->infinity f(x)-->1

Tags: math

I cannot find a function which I can use.

It has to have diminishing returns and f(0)=1/2 and when x-->infinity f(x)-->1 
Do any of you have a suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question is better asked at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math rather than programming.

Comment: You may want to look at a scaled and offset [arctangens](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctangens) function.

Comment: There are several functions that do this. Do you have any other criteria, like initial or final slope, or if the curvature is to be zero to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2/pi atan(x + 1)
```

Simple. `2/pi` for being a `1` on infinity and then solving equation: `2/pi atan(x) == 1/2` to get the offset: `1`.

**Wolfram:**

```
f[x_] := 2/\[Pi] ArcTan[x + 1];
f[0] (* 1/2 *)
Limit[2/\[Pi] ArcTan[x - Tan[1/2] - 1], x -> \[Infinity]] (* 1 *)
```